# How to make a translation for Qwik url routes?

Tags: routes, internationalization, url-routing, i18next, qwik

Currently, I am using `Qwik-Speak` to translate. I have to make translation for a whole Qwik app, including URL routes. For example:

```
src/
└── routes/
    ├── about-us/             
    │   └── index.tsx         # 'https:/.../en-US/about-us' in Eng or 'https:/.../om-oss in Swedish'
    └── layout.tsx
```

So is it possible to dynamically translate url route `/about-us` to `/om-oss` after switching to another language? And, of course, to save the functionality of the route.

P.S. The appearing of `en-US` in `https:/.../en-US/about-us` I figured out by using Qwik-Speak lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 0.16.0, Qwik Speak supports translated paths. Go to the documentation and follow *Tutorial: localized routing with url rewriting*